# Select cookie value based on string match

Tags: php

So I have this if statement where I am looking for a cookie:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['OptanonConsent'])) {
   ...
}
```

Next, I'm breaking the cookie up using the explode function:

```
$cookie_array = explode("&", $_COOKIE['OptanonConsent']);
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
array(9) { 
   [0]=> string(26) "landingPath=NotLandingPage" 
   [1]=> string(67) "datestamp=Tue+Apr+12+2022+07:16:23+GMT-0500+(Central+Daylight+Time)" 
   [2]=> string(14) "version=6.33.0" 
   [3]=> string(30) "groups=C0001:1,C0002:0,C0004:0" 
   [4]=> string(6) "hosts=" 
   [5]=> string(14) "isGpcEnabled=0" 
   [6]=> string(13) "geolocation=;" 
   [7]=> string(17) "isIABGlobal=false" 
   [8]=> string(23) "AwaitingReconsent=false" 
}
```

---

Next, I want to filter through and just grab the array index that has "groups" in it, using the following:

```
$groups_array = array_filter($cookie_array, static function($value) {
    return str_contains($value, 'groups');
});
```

Which outputs:

```
array(1) { 
  [3]=> string(30) "groups=C0001:1,C0002:0,C0004:0" 
}
```

---

Next, I want to search and see if "C0004:0" exists, so I'm using:

```
$targeting_cookie_disabled = in_array('C0004:0', $groups_array, true);
```

But that is returning a false return. The index changes always, so I can't use `$groups_array[3]`.

---

Does anyone know how to properly break up the cookie and grab just the "groups" index of an array and search through it?

Comment: It looks like your input data is basically a "query string" format, so instead of exploding & filtering, I would use `parse_str` - that gives you an array in which you will be able to access `groups` (and all the other parameters) directly.

Comment: _"The index changes always, so I can't use `$groups_array[3]`."_ - you can't use index-based _array access_ here to begin with - because you do not have an _array_, you have a string value. You will still have to split `C0001:1,C0002:0,C0004:0` _into_ an array first. Or, since you don't want to "access" `C0004` and get the value, but you are looking for `C0004:0` directly, you can also use `str_pos` on the string value directly.

Comment: Maybe you want to use [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) instead of that `in_array`

Comment: @CBroe, I'm attempting to use `$cookie = parse_str($_COOKIE['OptanonConsent'], $output);` which returns a NULL, is there something that I'm missing? It's throwing an `'void' function 'parse_str' result used` warning.

Comment: As you can see in [the manual about parse_str()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), it doesn't return the result. You need to pass a variable to store it in as the second variable. So instead of `$result = parse_str($theCookie);`, you need to do: `parse_str($theCookie, $result);`. Then you can use `$result` after.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, thank you, definitely didn't catch that - It works now.